# Bing Map WPF Control , Tile Source URL, Cookies?

Tags: wpf, cookies, wpf-controls, bing-maps, httpcookie

Bing Map WPF Control is not passing cookies(authentication details to access Tile Source URL) in each Tile Source Request. Is there any setting or hack in Bing Map WPF to enable this option ?. Thanks in advance.

```
        //Tile Source URL Example
        var URL = "https://www.sample.com/Z/X_Y.png";

        //Tile Source Layer
        var tileSourceLayer = new MapTileLayer()
        {
            TileSource = new TileSource() { UriFormat = URL }
        };
        MyBingMap.Children.Add(tileSourceLayer);
```

Comment: You may have a look at an [alternative control](http://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/) that provides greater flexibility in defining custom tile sources. And it's for free.

Answer (score 0):

We struggled with this question for a bit and the solution we came up with is a bit more complex than is ideal, but it works well.

The basic premise is that you overload `TileSource.GetUri()` method to return a path pointing at localhost, with parameters to indicate the real destination (Base64-encoded URL as well as the cookies you want sent, each as a URL parameter).

With the above complete, you simply need to setup an HTTP listener on another thread watching the given port. When requests hit that port, relay them to your map provider after setting the cookies and then relay the map provider response back to the Bing control.

Answer (score -1):

You can handle custom tile URL's by creating a custom tile source that creates the URL on the fly like so:

```
public class MyTileSource : TileSource
{
    private string _baseTileURL = "https://www.sample.com/{2}/{0}_{1}.png";

    public override Uri GetUri(int x, int y, int zoomLevel)
    {
        //{0} = X
        //{1} = Y
        //{2} = Z

        return new Uri(string.Format(_baseTileURL, x, y, zoomLevel));
    }
}
```

You can then implement this like so:

```
MyTileSource tileSource = new MyTileSource();
MapTileLayer tileLayer = new MapTileLayer()
{
    TileSource = tileSource
};

MyMap.Children.Add(tileLayer);
```

Using the tile layers you won't be able to cookies with your tile url requests. There is an update to the WPF map control coming soon which allows you to have a lot more flexibility around custom tile layers and it would be possible to do this.

Comment: This does not take care of passing the cookies to sample.com when the Bing control makes the requests for the tiles.

Comment: Unless you can fit it in a URI it won't be supported.